# Redefining 'section' environment to add margin to text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, environments, documentclass-writing

I'm writing a class and I would like to add a margin to the section, such that the text is aligned with the section title (and not with the section number as it is default).

Basically using the `quote` environment does the job:

```
\section{Title of section}
\begin{quote}
    \blindtext
\end{quote}
```

looks like this:

[image: example]

But I would like to somehow include this in the section command. It's important that the spacing in the title stays the same.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
 \usepackage{blindtext}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
    {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\color{LightSkyBlue}}%
    {\llap{\makebox[2em][l]{\thesection}}}%
    {0pt}% <---- what do I need here???
    {}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Here is my section title}
    \blindtext

    \end{document}
```

[image]